# Text Orientation from Edge/Skeleton (ToE/ToS)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I try to implement this paper https://www.mdpi.com/2076-3417/11/11/4852/pdf.
So I read the Text Orientation from Edge/Skeleton (ToE/ToS) thin search, how to do it and did not get any idea.

[image]

I already have the canny image, so how to measure the orientation the same way as the paper does?

Comment: maybe calculated from two sobels. impossible to say from the paper. contact the authors.